# Testing offline connection

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I'm currently writing a unit test that retrieves information from external service - I want to test a scenario when the given external is not reachable (so, either the client doesn't have outgoing access) or service is down.

So, it might be an obvious question, but how, for the purpose of the test, do I disable outbound connection, either in PHP / Laravel / Guzzle.

---

Per comment - code I want to test:

```
public function getRoadworks($bb)
{
    // assume that $bb = [0, 0, 1, 1];

    // can receive the response?
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request("GET", config('virtual-earth.api.base_url').implode(",", $bb), [
            'query' => [
                'key' => config('virtual-earth.credentials.key')
            ]
        ]);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: If its an external service, you should mock it and force behaviour you want to test. "You are not supposed" (pretty much opinion based) to use real third party when unit testing. Anyway, the mock is the way to go if you want to simulate error http codes, unexpected response etc... Can we have a look at how your test is settup please?

Comment: @olibiaz basically the first thing the function does is make a call to given service. The response is not stored within the object, so I cannot mock it

Comment: Can we have a look at the code please. Hard to help you "guessing" the code.

Comment: @olibiaz - added

Comment: It's actually quite easy to mock Guzzle responses - http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html

Comment: @MatthewDaly can you please provide how should I decouple the usage of `Client` within the function?

Comment: @eithed Use [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#automatic-injection) to get the Guzzle client rather than instantiating it in the class

Comment: @MatthewDaly I would do so, if the `Client` was necessary for the working of the class (ie. if I have `RetrieveInformationFromGoogle` class, the `Client` is necessary for this class to function). In this case the class method is dependant upon the `Client`, but the object can exist without `Client`. Why should I insert it, if in majority of cases, objects of this class won't require it?

Comment: @eithed I'm confused. You're saying you want to test the class above, which instantiates the Guzzle client inside a method, yet you're also saying it doesn't need the client? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158528/discussion-between-eithed-and-matthew-daly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @olibiaz for planting the idea in my head, that I'm more comfortable with, which is basically - injecting the `Service` into the method that requires it, rather than `Client`, so the code becomes:

```
public function getRoadworks($bb, Service $service)
{
    // assume that $bb = [0, 0, 1, 1];
    $data = $service->getData($bb);

    if (!$data)
        return false;

    ...
}
```

As such - yes, the injection proposed is still there, but this approach also allows to usage of different services, one of which is `VirtualEarthService`.

I understand that it doesn't answer my initial question - though it made me consider that if a given *thing* is not testable, then probably it shouldn't be done given way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Client()` is instanciate directly in the class you cannot, in the current state of your code, mock the client. If you have hand on the code, and are able to modify it, i advice you to add it in the function signature like that

```
public function getRoadworks(Client $httpClient = null)
{
   $bb = [0, 0, 1, 1];

  // can receive the response?
  try {
     $client = $httpClient ? : new Client();
     $response = $client->request("GET", config('virtual-earth.api.base_url').implode(",", $bb), [
        'query' => [
            'key' => config('virtual-earth.credentials.key')
        ]
     ]);
 }
 catch(\Exception $e)
 {
    return false;
 }

...
}
```

This way, you are still be backward compatible, so functions that use `getRoadworks` will still works and you will be able to mock the client. I agree that's not the best way, to change your code for testing purpose, but at the beginning this function is not properly designed for testing. Once done, you will be able to mock the client:

```
public function testFunction() {
  $clientMock = $this->getMockBuidder(ClientInterface::class)->getMock();

   $expectedResponse = ... // the response you want to mock
   $this->clientMock->expects($this->once())->method('request')
      ->willReturn($expectedResponse);

   // the method you want to test
   $object.getRoadworks($clientMock);

   // your assertions
}
```

Comment: So, your advice is to change the function for the purpose of testing? I'm also conflicted about the injection approach - basically now the function can receive a `Client` argument - how will any other dev looking only at the function determine that that attribute was introduced only for testing purposes?

Comment: Like i said, its maybe not an approach that is best in architecture perspective (injection or instanciation), but if you want to test it... i don't see any other way. And anyway, in my opinion, you should force the injection and remove the instanciation inside the function. So the devs should have no choice but inject it. In my example i keep it backward compatible, but force the injection is in my opinion the best approach. We should not instanciate Client inside a function. And if client is used in others function to your class, it should be in constructor rather than in the function istself